# How can I count how many \n (new lines) using python and regular expressions?

Tags: python, expression, multiline

Is there a way to count the number of lines in a set of text?  For example:

```
text="hello what are you"\
"doing with yourself"\
"this weekend?"
```

I want to count the "\n".  I know I could count this using regular python, but just wondering if there is a way to count this with Regular Expressions?

Comment: There is no `\n` (newline) in `text`.

Comment: it is one line, right?

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression that when I hit a HARD RETURN at the end of the line, it was "\n".  I see now (using pycharm) if I hold down the SHIFT key and the RETURN, I will get a "\n"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Side Note**

In your case there is no newline in `text`.

Probably you wanted to define

```
text = """hello what are you
doing with yourself
this weekend?"""
```

**Answer**

You don't need a regular expression.

Just use `text.count("\n")`~

Edit: Oh, nevermind. You need it to be a regex?

`len(re.findall("\n", text))` should work

Answer (score 1):

you can also use enumerate to count the lines in a file as follows:

```
with open (file, "r") as fp:
    for cnt, _ in enumerate (fp,1):
        pass
    print(cnt)
```

Comment: you could pass the start index to enumerate and avoid the last addition like this: enumerate(fp, 1)

Comment: @victorn. right, i will update with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use regular expressions to count newlines.

Run `re.findall()` and count the results.

```
len(re.findall('\n', text))
```

For example, on my Linux computer:

```
In [5]: with open('/etc/passwd') as fp: text = fp.read()

In [6]: len(re.findall('\n', text))
Out[6]: 56
```

But really, why would you? As you point out, there are already better ways to do it.